# Errors while installing mongo db

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I belong to a IT support team and i have the duty of installing mongodb in my organization so while trying to install mongodb on systems(fresh/not used ) sometimes mongo gets installed directly but majority of the times i am getting this error

root@goutham:mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.12
connecting to: test
2016-05-30T02:57:07.910-0400 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-05-30T02:57:07.915-0400 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed

How to solve the issue and how can i get to install mongo in a correct way all the time 
steps performed are :

1)apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

2)echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list

3)apt-get update

4)apt-get --force-yes -y install mongodb-org

5)echo "mongodb-org hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

6)echo "mongodb-org-server hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

7)echo "mongodb-org-shell hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

8)echo "mongodb-org-mongos hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

9)echo "mongodb-org-tools hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

any help ??? 
please :(

Comment: I have solved the issue i looked into the log where it showed that there is no space left in the device so in few off the systems there was no /data/db as well so i had to create them and try now its working fine

Comment: I solved it following this instructions https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu

Comment: Yea @Angel M  that was because of low disk space in few system anyways thanks for the help bro :)